# Facebook request dialog box not showing up on IE

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my facebook application i am using the facebook javascript sdk(code provided by facebook) to display dialog box(iframe) for sending app request to user friends. The iframe is working properly in firefox and chrome but not working in ie. Here's the code used

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected')
                {   var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
                            message: 'Checking App Request',
                            to: '<?php $i=0; foreach($friends as $id){if($i==50) break; echo($id.","); $i++;}?>',
                            title: 'Request',
                            display: 'iframe',
                            access_token: accessToken
                            }, requestCallback);
                }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug that is handled by people by setting `display` to `popup` value for IE. [Gist with example](https://gist.github.com/dandemeyere/1572523):

```
// Detect browser and set the compatible Dialog display type
div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<!--[if IE]><i></i><![endif]-->';
ie = div.getElementsByTagName('i').length === 1;
if (ie) {
  display = 'popup';
} else {
  display = 'iframe';
}

// Make the call
FB.ui({
  method: "apprequests",
  message: message,
  display: display,
  to: facebook_friend_id
}, function(response) {
  facebook_request_id = response.request_ids[0];
});
```